# Calling closures from an array in Rust

Tags: types, closures, rust

How do I iterate over an array of closures, calling each one in turn?

With functions, I discovered I could do this by just iterating over the array, and dereferencing the values that produced:

```
fn square(x: int) -> int { x * x }

fn add_one(x: int) -> int { x + 1 }

fn main() {
    let funcs  = [square, add_one];
    for func in funcs.iter() {
        println!("{}", (*func)(5i));
    }
}
```

However, when I try to do the same with closures, I get an error:

```
fn main() {
    let closures = [|x: int| x * x, |x| x + 1];
    for closure in closures.iter() {
        println!("{}", (*closure)(10i));
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
<anon>:4:24: 4:34 error: closure invocation in a `&` reference
<anon>:4         println!("{}", (*closure)(10i));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:4:9: 4:41 note: expansion site
<anon>:4:24: 4:34 note: closures behind references must be called via `&mut`
<anon>:4         println!("{}", (*closure)(10i));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:4:9: 4:41 note: expansion site
```

If I try declaring the iteration variable `ref mut`, it still doesn't work:

```
fn main() {
    let closures = [|x: int| x * x, |x| x + 1];
    for ref mut closure in closures.iter() {
        println!("{}", (*closure)(10i));
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
<anon>:4:24: 4:39 error: expected function, found `&|int| -> int`
<anon>:4         println!("{}", (*closure)(10i));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:4:9: 4:41 note: expansion site
```

If I add another dereference:

```
fn main() {
    let closures = [|x: int| x * x, |x| x + 1];
    for ref mut closure in closures.iter() {
        println!("{}", (**closure)(10i));
    }
}
```

I get back to the original error:

```
<anon>:4:24: 4:35 error: closure invocation in a `&` reference
<anon>:4         println!("{}", (**closure)(10i));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:4:9: 4:42 note: expansion site
<anon>:4:24: 4:35 note: closures behind references must be called via `&mut`
<anon>:4         println!("{}", (**closure)(10i));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:4:9: 4:42 note: expansion site
```

What am I missing here? Is there documentation somewhere that describes how this works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.iter()` method of vector yields immutable references, you need mutable ones to call the closure, thus you should use `.iter_mut()` :

```
fn main() {
    let mut closures = [|x: int| x * x, |x| x + 1];
    for closure in closures.iter_mut() {
        println!("{}", (*closure)(10i));
    }
}

-----

100
11
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Is there any way to force a closure to be immutable, so that it does not need to be called via a mutable ref, as an alternative way to solve the problem?

Comment: Hmm. Tried using the `unboxed_closures` feature gate to do this, with `[|&: x: int| x * x, |&: x: int| x + 1]`, but got the incsrutable error "error: mismatched types: expected \`closure\`, found \`closure\` (expected closure, found closure)". Anyhow, you answered my original question, I'll see if I can figure out the unboxed closure issue.

Comment: @BrianCampbell I was looking into this as well. Looks like unboxed closures are feature-gated for a reason. I think the type inference is still buggy.

Comment: What's the equivalent syntax for Rust 0.11, which does not feature iter_mut()?

Comment: @mcandre It will probably be `.mut_iter()`. However it's not really recommended to stay on a old version of Rust, the language is still rapidly changing.

Comment: @Levns I don't use 0.11 by choice, it's just a stepping stone from 0.10 to 0.12. I ducked out of the Rust world for a few months and...