# How can I iterate over a vector of functions and call each of them?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate over a vector of functions and execute each function at each step.

```
fn f1(i: i32) -> i32 {
    i * 2
}

fn f2(i: i32) -> i32 {
    i * 4
}

fn main() {
    let mut arr: Vec<|i32| -> i32> = Vec::new();
    arr.push(f1);
    arr.push(f2);

    for f in arr.iter() {
        println!("{}", f(1));
    }
}
```

But the attempted execution of `f(1)` gives this error:

```
error: expected function, found '&|i32| -> i32'
```

I guess in putting the functions in the vector their type is mutated and no longer works like a normal function. Is there a way to transform it back, or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you give a minimal reproducible example? What are `f1` and `f2` ?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301269/calling-closures-from-an-array-in-rust, but its answer is no longer valid (probably following the closure reform).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As of Rust 1.x, unboxed closures are the only kind of closures in the language, and they don't need a feature flag. Moreover, static functions can easily be converted to unboxed closures. Therefore, the correct way to call functions from a vector of functions is:

```
fn f1(i: i32) -> i32 { i * 2 }

fn f2(i: i32) -> i32 { i * 4 }

fn main() {
    let arr: Vec<&dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> = vec![&f1, &f2];

    for f in &arr {
        println!("{}", (f)(1));
    }
}
```

I've used `Fn()` closures which can access their environment through a shared reference, so it is sufficient to iterate the vector by reference. If I had used a `FnMut()` closure, I would have had to use iteration by mutable reference:

```
fn f1(i: i32) -> i32 { i * 2 }

fn f2(i: i32) -> i32 { i * 4 }

fn main() {
    let p1 = &mut f1;
    let p2 = &mut f2;

    let mut arr: Vec<&mut dyn FnMut(i32) -> i32> = vec![p1, p2];

    for f in &mut arr {
        println!("{}", (f)(1));
    }
}
```

A similar idea holds for `FnOnce()` and iteration by value, although here we need to use `Box` to own the closure:

```
fn f1(i: i32) -> i32 { i * 2 }

fn f2(i: i32) -> i32 { i * 4 }

fn main() {
    let arr: Vec<Box<dyn FnOnce(i32) -> i32>> = vec![Box::new(f1), Box::new(f1)];

    for f in arr {
        println!("{}", (f)(1));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you know that you only work with static functions, it is possible to store pointers to them directly, without using closure traits:

```
fn f1(i: i32) -> i32 { i * 2 }

fn f2(i: i32) -> i32 { i * 4 }

fn main() {
    let arr: Vec<fn(i32) -> i32> = vec![f1, f2];

    for f in &arr {
        println!("{}", (f)(1));
    }
}
```

While `f1` and `f2` actually have different incompatible types, they are automatically coerced to the general function pointer type `fn(i32) -> i32` when used in appropriate context, like in the example above.

Because static functions don't have any environment, you can freely clone references to them and call them through any kind of reference. This is probably *the* way to go if you only need static functions.

*This answer was updated for Rust 1.x; older versions of the answer remain in [the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27312410/revisions).*

Comment: Isn't there a way to indicate in the closure signature that it will NOT mutate its environment?

Comment: @MatthieuM., there is, with unboxed closures. Old closures always capture their environment by mutable reference.

Comment: I filed an issue on unboxed closures [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19564).